# how to send empty formData values using swagger specification?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Please find below the sample JSON I tried using allowEmptyValue option,

```
               {
                    "name": "p[1]",
                    "in": "formData",
                    "description": "abc",
                    "type": "number",
                    "allowEmptyValue": true,
                },
                {
                    "name": "p[2]",
                    "in": "formData",
                    "description": "def",
                    "type": "string",
                    "allowEmptyValue": true,
                },
                {
                    "name": "p[3]",
                    "in": "formData",
                    "description": "ghi",
                    "allowEmptyValue": true,
                    "type": "number",
                }
```

When an empty value is passed to p[1], swagger frames the request url as 
-F  -F  -F  -F  where it should be p[]-F p[]-F... so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.